# Tree layout algorithm for a mindmap with summary feature

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout, tree, mindmap

I am planning to implement a mindmap with a summary feature using JavaScript. The layout should roughly look like the image attached (summary feature in Xmind.app).

However, I am not sure how to layout the summary. Are there any papers, tutorials, implementations or sample codes or anything available for the layout algorithm of the summary feature?

Thank you.

[image]

**What i have done so far:**

Currently, I have implemented the basic layout of the mindmap using d3 and d3-flextree.

However, d3 and d3-flextree only support regular node layouts and do not support the summary feature.

[image]

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Eureka Sorry, I have updated the question. Could you please take a look again?

Comment: Each topic has a list of subtopics. In terms of data representation, isn’t that just a n-ary tree?

Comment: yeah，the normal tree node in mindmap make it's just a n-ary tree, but the summary is different with normal tree node. @AbhinavMathur